# Firebase Firestore security rules based on reference data type

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Firestore I have a collection of items with an owner.

The owner can be a user, who should be allowed to read his documents.

With a `userId` you could do like this:

```
allow read, write: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
```

But with an `owner` reference field there is seemingly no documentation when it comes to security rules.

I tried this security rule:

```
allow read, write: if resource.data.owner == 'users/$(request.auth.uid)';
```

and querying like this:

```
const owner = this.db.collection('/users').doc(auth.uid).ref;

const collection = this.db.collection('/items',
  (ref) => ref.where('owner', '==', owner)
);
```

but I'm still getting **Missing or insufficient permissions**.

Answer (score 3):

References are considered as [paths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path) in security rules, so you can compare it with

```
function checkUser() {
  return request.resource.data.userReference == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid);
}
```

It's important to use the full path with `databases/$(database)/documents` in front. In this scenario, I have a collection named `users`, and each user id is their `uid` (it looks like you are also doing that)

Answer (score 2):

Both these rules work for me in Simulator (Firebase console):

```
allow read, write: if resource.data.owner == 'users/' + request.auth.uid;
```

and

```
allow read, write: if path(resource.data.owner) == /users/$(request.auth.uid);
```

But not in the query from my code.